# Prometheus errors and log location

Tags: docker, prometheus

I have a Prometheus service running in a docker container and we have a group of servers that are rotating reporting up and down with the error "context deadline exceeded".

Our time interval is 15 seconds and timeout is 10 second.

The servers have been polled with no issues for months, no new changes have been identified. At first I suspected a networking issues but I have triple checked the entire path and all containers and everything is okay. I have even tcpdumped on the destination server and Prometheus polling server and can see the connections establish and complete, yet still being reported as down.

Can anyone tell me where I can find logs relating to "content deadline exceeded"? Is there any additional information I can find on what is causing this?

From other thread it seems like this is a timeout issue, but the servers are a subsecond away and again there is no packetloss occurring anywhere.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What config are you using? Where are the services running? Context deadline exceeded seems like an issue reaching the docker socket but without more info it’s hard to tell

Comment: One test you should do is execute curl -i on the port where the data should be and check if the metrics are instantly printed